# Remove the first part of each line of a text file

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, sed

I am trying to edit a text file which has multiple lines that look like this:

```
avaya logs 20171202 000000 (9).txt: 660119211mS CMLOGGING: CALL:2017/12/0111:14,00:00:16,008,203,O,208,208,Jon,,,1,,""n/a,0
```

I want to remove everything before where it says `CALL` on every line. 
I think the `sed` command can do this but I am not very familiar with it. 
How can I do this?

Comment: @dsstorefile Post an answer if you're going to post an answer. I've edited your comment per the replies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `awk` in the following way:

```
awk -F "CALL" '{print "CALL"$2}' filename
```

The result is:

```
CALL:2017/12/0111:14,00:00:16,008,203,O,208,208,Jon,,,1,,""n/a,0
```

Details:

1. Use the `-F` or `--field-separator` flag, and setting **CALL** to be the field seperator
2. Print the string "CALL" followed by
3. The second element in the line (when **CALL** is the separator)

> Note: You can redirect the output into another file using:
>
> `awk -F "CALL" '{print "CALL"$2}' filename  > newfilename`

Answer (score 2):

With sed:

```
sed -e 's/.*CALL:/CALL:/' input.txt > output.txt
```

If you want to edit the input file in place add the `-i` option.

Comment: Why not directly edit `input.txt` with `sed -i ... input.txt`?